# Add Image URL to PHPExcel

Tags: image, phpexcel

Background: I have been tasked with creating Excel spreadsheets dynamically from a PHP-based webserver such that the webserver is notified when the spreadsheet is opened by the end user. My solution is to use an image URL with a get query string that identifies the end user and the document so I can log that it was opened. If there is a better solution, please let me know and I will happily abandon this attempt to meet the project requirements.

I can make a PHPExcel document without trouble and send it to the user when the user clicks the "download report" button. I can insert an image. However, I have to use a GD image that I create from a local file. I'm using the logo, so I insert images/logo.png into the spreadsheet. That works without a problem.

What I'm trying to find is an example that uses a URL instead of a local image. I want to insert something like http://example.com/images/logo.png?u=123&r=456 into the spreadsheet. Then, when the user opens it, the image is pulled from the server and I can log the user and report numbers. I haven't tried anything because I can't find any documentation that discusses doing this. All of the examples that I find are for inserting a local image, not a URL-based image.

UPDATE: After a couple weeks of research before asking this question and answers received from websites like this one, I do not believe this is possible. It can be done using a macro. However, a macro will certainly be blocked by Excel for a spreadsheet downloaded from the web or received in email. OpenOffice Calc allows linking data to a foreign source using a URL. That feature does not translate to Excel. Further, it pops up a "Do you want to update the foreign data?" prompt when you open the document and has "no" highlighted.

I also received a lot of comments from other websites that this sort of "feature" is an invasion of privacy. I send you a spreadsheet and then I know your IP address when you open it. That is not the purpose. This is for tracking private health data for patients that has been stored in a spreadsheet. I want to record who received the original spreadsheet (the user number) and which report is in the spreadsheet (the report number). Then, I should see it open up a few times at a local IP address. If it starts popping up at IP addresses elsewhere, I have an alert that the private health information could have been compromised. If it starts popping up at multiple places at the same time, I really know it has been compromised and I can alert the patients to let them know what information was in the file. Therefore, I believe that this is a protection of privacy project, not a clear cut invasion of privacy project.

Comment: Would you be able to do this directly in MS Excel itself? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: @MarkBaker I have been working on that. I haven't figured out how to do it in Excel itself for an image. I've also been looking at document management (DRM) tools for Excel to see if I can find anything there. No luck so far.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only way to do it in MS Excel would be with an autorun macro (and MS Excel will typically disable that option on any file downloaded from the web, because of the potential for spreading malware)... and PHPExcel doesn't support macros anyway

Comment: I can see that it is possible with a macro, but I agree that macros will be blocked. I know that an image with a get string can be blocked as well. I found that OpenOffice Calc lets you have embedded HTML from a foreign website (without images), but it doesn't translate to Excel. So, I am going to pass up to the administration that this is not doable at this time and edit this question to notate why I don't think it is possible in case someone reads this in the future.

Comment: That's right; MS Excel embeds all images in the fie itself, so they can be visible even when there's no internet connection, which means that the traditional email-type approach of an http image request that can be logged on a server simply isn't an option in Excel